# How to redirect interactive prompt messages for input to a file

Tags: powershell, stdin

I have a folder with a file inside it:

```
C:\tmp\a\file.txt
```

When I am trying to delete this folder with:

```
rd c:\tmp\a
```

I am receiving the system input message:
[image]

I want to redirect this message to a file.
I tried any of the suggested redirections operators from:
https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-redirection.html

But none of them worked for me.
I also tried the `*>` operator:
[image]

When I am trying the basic `>` operator it just send me the system message:
[image]

The real reason I am trying to do this redirection is because I am working on a reverse shell between a client and a server. When the server is trying to delete a folder from the client the question goes to the client and not to the server.
So I first want to understand how to do this basic redirection before trying it over the network.

Comment: [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection): *NOTE: The All (\*), Warning (3), Verbose (4) and Debug (5) redirection operators were introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0. They do not work in earlier versions of Windows PowerShell.* And you are using PowerShell v2. And, BTW, output redirection operators does not allow you to redirect confirmation message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried piping the Out-File command to the function?

```
rd c:\tmp\a | Out-File -FilePath C:\tmp\a\file.txt
```

Also, I must mention that you are attempting to delete the folder 'a' but then attempting to output text to a file that would be in that folder. This seems quite odd to me; however, maybe I am misinterpreting something.

Comment: I tried the command you wrote and I still receive the system message. Regarding the logic problem that I am trying to send info toa file inside this folder, you can change the folder path to other place, it doesn't matter to me. Anyway the system message should be redirect to the file before deleting => it won't delete because I won't choose "yes".

Comment: Okay, that makes a bit more sense. So from my research rd or Remove-Item does not have an output. I think the only option you have is to specify that you want the function to be performed recursive and verbose. This will of course delete the folder and the files indefinitely though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Start-Transcript` to redirect console output to a file.

```
Start-Transcript -path C:\output.txt -append
# do some stuff
Stop-Transcript
```

This will redirect the output the file C:\output.txt

Comment: This is a little progress. It does move the output to the file but it does not **redirects** it. I wanted it to redirect => I should not see any messages in the console because I am **redirecting** them.